# An inequality about convexity of the function $(1/x-x)^\alpha$.

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^+$ with $a+b+c<1$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Prove that $$\Big(\frac1a-a\Big)^\alpha+\Big(\frac1b-b\Big)^\alpha+\Big(\frac1c-c\Big)^\alpha\geq3\Big(\frac3{a+b+c}-\frac{a+b+c}3\Big)^\alpha.$$

I tried to use Jensen's inequality, but the function $f(x):=(1/x-x)^\alpha$ is not necessarily convex on $(0,1)$, as $$f''(x)=\frac{\alpha(1/x-x)^\alpha(1-4x^2-x^4+\alpha(1+x^2)^2)}{x^2(x^2-1)^2}$$ becomes negative when $\alpha<1$ and $x$ is close to $1$. I got stuck here.

Comment: Sadly it is not convex when $\alpha <1$. See for eg. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Fx+-x)%5E(1%2F3)+,+0%3Cx%3C1 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Fx+-x)%5E(45%2F952)+,+0%3Cx%3C1